# "Element type "TextView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>">

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

So here's the short code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"


    <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="Your total is 0"
       android:textSize="45dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:gravity="center" 
       android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    </TextView>       

    <Button            
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="Add one"
       android:textSize="20dp" 
       android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    />


    <Button
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="Subtract one"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/bSubtract"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using Eclipse and targeting for FroYo API Level 8. Mac oS X 10.8.2 EClipse juno
I'm following tutorials by TheNewBoston and so I copied his code, and it's the exact same yet I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 5):

Both will work

```
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Your total is 0"
    android:textSize="45dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay" />
```

OR

```
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Your total is 0"
    android:textSize="45dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 1):

your LinearLayout at the top isnt closed

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax in the XML is wrong.
Replace the TextView you have:

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Your total is 0"
android:textSize="45dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center" 
android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
</TextView>
```

with:

```
<TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Your total is 0"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the element.

Try this

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="Your total is 0"
     android:textSize="45dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:gravity="center" 
     android:id="@+id/tvDisplay">
</TextView>
```

or this

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="Your total is 0"
     android:textSize="45dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:gravity="center" 
     android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"/>
```